# Unity xCode signing issues when reimporting a project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, signing

I develop a Unity 5.3.5f application on Windows, one of my target platforms is iOS(xCode version 8.2.1). When I make changes, I upload my project to Dropbox, which is shared between my Windows computer and virtual MacOS machine. When I download the updated Unity project from Dropbox to MacOS(I delete all outdated information, including Unity and xCode projects and copy the new updated one) and build it, sometimes I get strange signing errors in xCode. They are:

> The operation couldn't be completed. Unable to log in with account
>   'account mail'. An unexpected failure occured while loggin
>   in(Underlying error code 1100).
>
> Provisioning profile "profile name" doesn't include signing
>   certificate "iPhone developer: name (some ID)".
>
> Provisioning profile "profile name" doesn't support the Game Center
>   and In-App Purchase capabilities.

And sometimes it gives no errors. `Automatically manage signing` is on by default.

Cleaning, re-opening, checking-unchecking `Automatically manage signing` and restarting the virtual machine and even rebuilding xCode Project from the very beginning did not help. Solution is to re-login, clean and restart xCode.

Interesting thing is that this issue is only for this one xCode project, I mean, that if I open some other project there are no signing issues and it is logged in successfully.

Why does this issue come up in the first place? What do I do to avoid these errors?